# How to get Serializer object from Column Family Comparator?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I would like to convert a column name from ByteBuffer into the corresponding object (String, Long, etc). I noticed each serializer has a getComparator() method which one can use to find the comparator given the serializer.

Is it possible to do the inverse: find the serializer for column name from comparator?

Comment: See the "hector" tag :) ?

Comment: @Eugen Have you managed to find a way? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @forhas Not sure if this might be useful to you too but you can get the Serializer for a column value by calling `SerializerTypeInferer.getSerializer(yourColumnValueObject)`

Comment: Thank you! I will sure give it try.